# How to Print in Console Using com.strobel.decompiler.PlainTextOutput

Tags: java, printing, console, decompiler

I am using Proycon library for my application, PlainTextOutput is a class inside Proycon library,

during googling I have found the code block given below.what does this means, can I print to console using this code ?

```
com.strobel.decompiler.Decompiler.decompile(
         "D:\\BuildConfig.class",new com.strobel.decompiler.PlainTextOutput(new java.io.OutputStreamWriter(System.out)));
```

Comment: Looks like the relevant code has been changed. It's now DecompilerDriver.decompileJar/Type and the interface is different.

Comment: @Antimony No, that's just the entry point for the command-line decompiler.  The code used above is a public utility class for interfacing easily with the decompiler.

Comment: @Mike Sorry. I must have been looking in the wrong place.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be an oversight in the implementation; it's not flushing the `Writer` for you.  Try this:

```
final PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(System.out);

try {
    com.strobel.decompiler.Decompiler.decompile(
        "D:\\BuildConfig.class",
        new com.strobel.decompiler.PlainTextOutput(writer)
    );
}
finally {
    writer.flush();
}
```

I'll look into fixing this for the next Procyon release.